# Plotting integral in sagemath gives `verbose 0 (3839: plot.py, generate_plot_points)`

Tags: python, sage

I plotted integral of function `x^2*sin(x^2)` in SageMath.

It gives the following warnings and plot:

```py
sage: plot(integrate(x^2*sin(x^2), x), (x, -6, 6))
```

```
verbose 0 (3839: plot.py, generate_plot_points) WARNING:
  When plotting, failed to evaluate function at 35 points.
verbose 0 (3839: plot.py, generate_plot_points) Last
  error message: 'unable to simplify to float approximation'
Launched png viewer for Graphics object consisting of 129 graphics primitives
```

[image: Plot of integral with SageMath]

How can i fix it?

Comment: please post the code here, in this way you may get a faster answer.

Comment: plot(integrate(x^2*sin(x^2), x), (x, -6, 6))
i've just used it

Comment: You should have also some module(s) imported, why not sharing it?!

Comment: i didn't use another modules for plotting it. Did u see image posted in my question?